# R, charater with <U+200B>

Tags: r, unicode, character, width, zero

I imported a table from an excel.

If I open this table (as dataframe) from the environment it looks fine:

```
Name  Ser_NR 
ABC   123
DEF   458
EGS   954
```

However, I noted that for some rows, the filter function doesn't work.
Then I put this dataframe into Console,
It shows me this:

```
Name  Ser_NR 
ABC   123
DEF   458<U+200B>
EGS   954 <U+200B>
```

The type of this column "Ser_NR" is character.
I want "remove" <U+200B> or change the type to normal character.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: U+200B is the unicode for a zero width space. I'm not sure if `trimws()` would clear this. If you could `dput(sample_data)` into the question we could test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
df$Ser_NR <- as.integer(df$Ser_NR)
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with regex:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble::tribble(
         ~Name,       ~Ser_NR,
         "ABC",         "123",
         "DEF", "458<U+200B>",
         "EGS", "954<U+200B>"
         )

df %>% 
  mutate(Ser_NR = gsub("<([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*)(.[^>]*)>([.^<]*)", "\\3", Ser_NR))
```

Which gives us:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Name  Ser_NR
  <chr> <chr> 
1 ABC   123   
2 DEF   458   
3 EGS   954
```